# How can I pass parameters from View Model via Repository to the Dao

Tags: android, android-room, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

I am creating application with following architecture: Room Database <-> Repository <-> View Model <-> Fragments. What I want to achieve is to execute queries from View Model via Repository via Dao object with some given variables. I have created query for selecting some data from the table in Dao object:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM meal_table WHERE mealDate = :date") 
public LiveData<MealWithProducts> getMealWithProductsFromDate(String date);
```

Then I have set fixed value in Repository class for testing purposes, something like:

MealWithProductsRepository.class

```
public class MealWithProductsRepository {

    private final MealWithProductsDao mealWithProductsDao;
    private final LiveData<MealWithProducts> mealWithProductsFromDate;

    public MealWithProductsRepository(Application application){
        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mealWithProductsDao = db.mealWithProductsDao();
        mealWithProductsFromDate = mealWithProductsDao.getMealWithProductsFromDate("15-08-2021");
    }

    public LiveData<MealWithProducts> getMealWithProductsFromDate() {
        return mealWithProductsFromDate;
    }

}
```

DiaryEntryViewModel.class

```
public class DiaryEntryViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final MealWithProductsRepository mealWithProductsRepository;
    private final LiveData<MealWithProducts> mealWithProductsFromDate;


    public DiaryEntryViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        mealWithProductsRepository = new MealWithProductsRepository(application);
        mealWithProductsFromDate = mealWithProductsRepository.getMealWithProductsFromDate();
    }

    public LiveData<MealWithProducts> getMealWithProductsFromDate() { return mealWithProductsFromDate; }


}
```

I have tested this single case and it worked, however I do not know how to pass parameters from View Model class into the repository since this query is executed in Repository constructor as well as Repository reference in View Model is created in View Model constructor. Could You please point me a direction on how should I proceed further with this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DiaryEntryViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private final MealWithProductsRepository mealWithProductsRepository;
    private final LiveData<MealWithProducts> mealWithProductsFromDate;


    public DiaryEntryViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);

        mealWithProductsRepository = new MealWithProductsRepository(application);
    }

    public LiveData<MealWithProducts> getMealWithProductsFromDate(String date) { return mealWithProductsRepository.getMealWithProductsFromDate(); }


}
```

```
public class MealWithProductsRepository {

    private final MealWithProductsDao mealWithProductsDao;
    private final LiveData<MealWithProducts> mealWithProductsFromDate;

    public MealWithProductsRepository(Application application){
        AppDatabase db = AppDatabase.getDatabase(application);
        mealWithProductsDao = db.mealWithProductsDao();
    }

    public LiveData<MealWithProducts> getMealWithProductsFromDate(String date) {
        return mealWithProductsDao.getMealWithProductsFromDate(date);
    }

}
```

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM meal_table WHERE mealDate = :date") 
public LiveData<MealWithProducts> getMealWithProductsFromDate(String date);
```

Why Don't you use like this?

Comment: Thank You Gulab. I feel stupid that this was so plain and simple :) I think I felt into the trap of following tutorials too closely which ended in narrow view of the problem. Thanks again!